# Python @patch.dict vs @patch.object

Tags: python

I have the following file:

```
# dummy.py

import os
from requests import get
def my_func():
    name = os.environ.get('name')
    response = get('http://www.google.com')
    return name, response.content
```

and the following test file

```
import unittest
import os
import requests
from ddt import ddt, data, unpack
from mock import patch, Mock, MagicMock
from dummy import my_func


mock_response = Mock()
mock_response.content = "...content"


@ddt
@patch.dict(os.environ, {"name": "patched"})
@patch.object(requests, requests.get.__name__, return_value=mock_response)
class TestDummy(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dummy(self, mock_get):
        name, content = my_func()
        print("name: {}".format(name))
        print("content: {}".format(content))
```

I was thinking these two lines have similar behaviors.

```
@patch.dict(os.environ, {"name": "patched"})
@patch.object(requests, requests.get.__name__, return_value=mock_response)
```

However, when running the test, `os.environ` was patched, but `requests` was NOT patched.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

`my_func` doesn't use `requests.get`; it uses `dummy.get`, which is *initialized* using the value of `requests.get` before you patch `requests`.

```
@ddt
@patch.dict(os.environ, {"name": "patched"})
@patch('dummy.get', return_value=mock_response)
class TestDummy(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dummy(self, mock_get):
        name, content = my_func()
        print("name: {}".format(name))
        print("content: {}".format(content))
```

Answer (score 0):

If change the source file to the following, it will work.

```
import os
import requests


def my_func():
    name = os.environ.get('name')
    response = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
    return name, response.content
```